# Regex to match whole sentence but with exeptions

Tags: regex

I use this regex to mark whole sentences ending in period, question mark or exclamation mark - it works so far.

```
[A-Z][^.!?]*[.?!]
```

But there are two problems:

1. if there is a number followed by a period in the sentence.
2. if there is an abbreviation with a period in the sentence.

Then the sentence is extracted incorrectly.
Example:

> 1. Sentence Example: "Er kam am 1. November."

> 2. Sentence Example: "Dr. Schiwago."

The first sentence then becomes two sentences because a period follows the number.
The second sentence then also becomes two sentences because the abbreviation ends in a period.

How can I adjust the regex so that both problems do not occur?

So in the first sentence, whenever a period follows a number, this should not be seen as the end of the sentence, but the regex continues to the next period.

In the second sentence, for example, a minimum size of 4 characters would ensure that the abbreviation is not seen as a complete sentence.

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/2mZayI/1)

Comment: Senteces like "I was born in 1999." will cause problems. While solutions suggested below won't process them corretly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
\b(?:\d+\.\s*[A-Z]|(?:[DJS]r|M(?:rs?|(?:is)?s))\.|[^.!?])*[.?!]
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/2mZayI/3). Add the known abbreviations and other patterns you come across as alternatives to the non-capturing group.

- `\b` - word boundary (**Note**: add `(?=[A-Z])` after `\b` if you need to start matching with an uppercase letter)
- `(?:\d+\.\s*[A-Z]|(?:[DJS]r|M(?:rs?|iss))\.|[^.!?])*` - zero or more occurrences of:

  - `\d+\.\s*[A-Z]` - one or more digits, `.`, zero or more whitespaces, uppercase letter
  - `|` - or
  - `(?:[DJS]r|M(?:rs?|(?:is)?s))\.` - `Dr.`, `Jr.`, `Sr.`, `Mr`, `Mrs`, `Ms`, `Miss`
  - `|` - or
  - `[^.!?]` - a char other than `.`, `!` and `?`
- `[.?!]` - a `.`, `?` or `!` char.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Any change to put "number-period-number" rule inside the regex? For example "9.9" oder "245.72"

Comment: @user3392296 Just replace `\d+\.\s*[A-Z]` with `\d+\.(?:\d+|\s*[A-Z])`

Answer (score 1):

Try ([regex101](https://regex101.com/r/J6L1Mn/1))

```
[A-Z].*?(?<!Dr)(?<!\d)\s*[.!?]
```

---

- **`[A-Z]`** - start with capital letter
- **`.*?`** - non-greedy *match-all*
- **`(?<!Dr)(?<!\d)\s*[.!?]`** - we match until `.`, `!` or `?`, there must not be `Dr` or digit before it.